# Why is clang's `-O3` alloca 2x faster than g++

Tags: memory-management, compiler-construction, clang, micro-optimization

[On the use and abuse of alloca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807612/on-the-use-and-abuse-of-alloca)

Got some benchmarks at the bottom of a previous question. clang clearly has a better implementation in the `-O3` optimizer profile. What gives? Is clang cutting any corners? Also, since clang is a modern compiler, are there any safeties or other interesting properties in its alloca implementation?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but: If clang maps `alloca` to the LLVM `alloca` instruction, the (widely-used as it takes care of creating a well-formed SSA) `Reg2Mem` pass can transform it into using LLVM-level registers, which get all the optimizations LLVM provides for normal variables.

Answer (score 4):

Guess by delnan is true. But he didn't account that test is very bad, and clang can to optimize out actual `alloca` operation from `alloca_test`.

`alloca_test` have only llvm ir operation alloca, but no `alloca()` function call:

```
%11 = call i32 @_Z18random_string_sizev()
%12 = alloca i8, i32 %11
```

Compare with `malloc_test`:

```
%11 = call i32 @_Z18random_string_sizev()
%12 = call i8* @malloc(i32 %11)
```

Even with `-O1` there is no more alloca in `alloca_test`:

```
define void @_Z11alloca_testv() nounwind {
; <label>:0
  %1 = tail call i32 @_Z18random_vector_sizev()
  %2 = icmp sgt i32 %1, 0
  br i1 %2, label %.lr.ph, label %._crit_edge

.lr.ph:                                           ; preds = %.lr.ph, %0
  %i.01 = phi i32 [ %4, %.lr.ph ], [ 0, %0 ]
  %3 = tail call i32 @_Z18random_string_sizev()
  %4 = add nsw i32 %i.01, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %4, %1
  br i1 %exitcond, label %._crit_edge, label %.lr.ph

._crit_edge:                                      ; preds = %.lr.ph, %0
  ret void
}
```

And for `malloc_test`, malloc call is still here:

```
%6 = tail call i32 @_Z18random_string_sizev()
%7 = tail call i8* @malloc(i32 %6)
```

I should also say that `g++ -O3` (tested 4.1 and 4.5.2) doesn't optimize out changing size of stack (alloca main effect).

Comment: well semantically the effect is the same no ? Inlining the alloca semantics vs using a llvm il call, the memory is still created on a stack frame ?

Comment: I don't know, if llvm allow to "call" alloca (how can called function change stack size of caller), but the alloca ir op is in basic ir operations set. http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#i_alloca