# When to free pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management

I'm a bit of a C newbie, so I'm still trying to get my head fully around when to worry about memory issues.

Suppose I have the following simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

/* this returns a malloc()'d string */
char *get_str(int whichone);

int main(void)
{
    char *s;

    if ((s = get_str(0)) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    /* position 1 */

    if ((s = get_str(1)) == NULL) { /* position 2 */
        exit(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this simple of a program has no worries about memory. It allocates a few bytes (for all intents and purposes), and it exits provided our dear function didn't fail.

Now, suppose I am running similar code inside of a looping and `fork()`ing program. Should I be using `free(s)` at position 1 since at position 2 I leave the old value behind and assign a new location for the pointer?

Comment: in one word: yes. the same applies when you exit from the scope.

Comment: You dont free a *pointer*, you free the memory *object* that it **points to**. BTW: your code will leak memory if the get_str() actually allocates memory.

Comment: You mean it will leak memory if I do not `free()` the memory being pointed to, correct?

Comment: Correct. Because the pointer `s` is the only way to get to the object. By assigning again to `s`, it's previous content (the address of the first `getstr()` result) is overwritten.

Comment: Is there any OS that supports `fork()` but does not free any unfreed memory when exiting the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definetly `free` the memory at position 1, because once you reassigned `s` you lost any chance to do so. And I'd do it one way or another because you can never know when somebody else is instructed to build a fork into your application and he will assume you did everything right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `free` releases the memory associated with the pointer that is being `free`'d. Once you reassign `s` so that it holds a different memory location, you will have lost your opportunity to free the memory associated with the original value of `s`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pointer to memory that have been allocated using one of the `malloc()` type calls then when you are done with the memory area, you should deallocate the memory using `free()`.  Similarly using `calloc()`, which also allocates from the heap, should be followed by the use `free()` to deallocate the memory when done with it.

The other memory allocator such as `alloca()` which allocates from the stack and not the heap see [On the use and abuse of alloca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807612/on-the-use-and-abuse-of-alloca) does not use the `free()` function and that memory will be recovered automatically as the stack pointers are adjusted when the function in which it is used returns.  Naturally that means that using a pointer from `alloca()` is only good for the function and any functions it calls and the address becomes invalid as soon as the function using `alloca()` returns.

In your simple example, I would use `free()` just before the call to the `get_str(1)` function at position 2 so the source would look something like"

```
int main(void)
{
    char *s;

    if ((s = get_str(0)) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // doing stuff with the string pointed to by s
    /* position 1 */

    // free up the string area so that we can get another one.
    free (s);
    if ((s = get_str(1)) == NULL) { /* position 2 */
        exit(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I might also be tempted to modify your example a touch and do something like the following.  This was all written **without testing in a compiler** so there may be a compilation error or two however this should provide the basic idea.

The idea with this approach is to have a struct that contains state information as well as a pointer so that you will know which type of `get_str()` pointer came from, if you are interested, and when you call the `get_str()` function, it will deallocate the memory for you.  You could also add intelligence so that if there is memory already allocated and it is the correct type, then you do not do a `free()` followed by a `malloc()` but instead just return back.

Another bonus provided by this approach is when a `free()` is done, the `char *` member of the struct is set to NULL which should give you a crash if you try to dereference the pointer and since the `whichone` member of the struct indicates the last type of `get_str()` used, your debugging may be easier depending on how good you are with interpreting a crash dump.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int   whichone;
   char  *s;
} GetStrStruct;

/* this returns a malloc()'d string */
GetStrStruct *get_str(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct)
{

    free(pStruct->s);  // we depend on pStruct->s being valid or NULL here
    pStruct->s = NULL;
    pStruct->whichone = -1;
    switch (whichOne) {
    case 0:     // allocate string one
        pStruct->s =  malloc (32);   // string one type of memory allocation
        pStruct->whichone = whichone;
        break;
     case 1:     // allocate string two
        pStruct->s = malloc (64);   // string two type of memory allocation
        pStruct->whichone = whichone;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    // if the malloc() failed then return a NULL pointer
    // we just reuse the pStruct pointer here, it is local and one less variable to make
    if (pStruct->s == NULL) pStruct = NULL;

    return pStruct;
}


int main(void)
{
    GetStrStruct myStruct = {0};   // create and initialize the struct

    if (get_str(0, &myStruct) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // do things with myStruct.s, the string from last get_str() call
    // this would be using myStruct.s and not just myStruct or s so maybe awkward?
    /* position 1 */

    if (get_str(1, &myStruct) == NULL) { /* position 2 */
        exit(2);
    }

    // do things with the second type of get_str()
    // this would be using myStruct.s and not just myStruct or s so maybe awkward?

    // release the memory as I am done.  This may seem a bit strange to get a nothing string.
    get_str (-1, &myStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

If you added a debug facility you could even track which line of source did the last allocation and the last deallocation.  Or if the `malloc()` fails, you could implement a debugger interrupt or other mechanism to immediately stop so you will know exactly which line the function call failed.

In the include file with the prototype for the `get_str()` function and the `GetStrStruct` struct you would use C Preprocessor as follows.  If you change the 0 in the `#if 0` to a 1 then the debug version is enabled otherwise it is not.  The idea is to use a macro through the C Preprocessor to replace calls to `get_str()` with a call to `get_str_Debug()` and provide additional arguments with the source file path and the line number in the source file.

```
#if 0
        typedef struct {
           int   whichone;
           char  *s;
           struct  {
              int  lineNo;
              char  file[64];
           } myDebug;
        } GetStrStruct;

GetStrStruct *get_str_Debug(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct, char *file, int line);
#define get_str(wo,ps)  get_str_Debug (wo,ps,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#else
        typedef struct {
           int   whichone;
           char  *s;
        } GetStrStruct;
GetStrStruct *get_str(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct);

#endif
```

And then in the implementation file you could use the C Preprocessor with something like the following to allow you to specify whether the `get_str()` function should be replaced by a `get_str_Debug()` function with additional debug aids at compile time.

```
#if defined(get_str)
    // provide a prototype for the replacement function signature.
    GetStrStruct *get_str_Special(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct);

    // provide the debug information wrapper so that we can track where the last use came from
    GetStrStruct *get_str_Debug(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct, char *file, int line)
    {
        GetStrStruct *pTemp = get_str_Special (whichone, pStruct);

        if (pTemp) {
            // update the debug information.  we keep only last 60 chars of file path.
            int iLen = strlen (file);

            if (iLen > 60) iLen -= 60; else ilen = 0;
            strcpy (pStruct->myDebug.file, file + iLen);
            pStruct->myDebug.lineNo = line;
        } else {
            // cause a debugger interrupt or a crash dump or something.
        }

        return pTemp;
    }

GetStrStruct *get_str_Special (int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct)
#else

    /* this returns a malloc()'d string */
    GetStrStruct *get_str(int whichone, GetStrStruct *pStruct)
#endif
    {

        free(pStruct->s);
        pStruct->s = NULL;
        pStruct->whichone = -1;
        switch (whichOne) {
        case 0:     // allocate string one
            pStruct->s =  malloc (32);   // string one type of memory allocation
            pStruct->whichone = whichone;
            break;
         case 1:     // allocate string two
            pStruct->s = malloc (64);   // string two type of memory allocation
            pStruct->whichone = whichone;
            break;
       default:
            break;
        }

        // if the malloc() failed then return a NULL pointer
        if (pStruct->s == NULL) pStruct = NULL;

        return pStruct;
    }
```

Then where ever you use `get_str()` if you turn on the debugging, the C Preprocessor will substitute a call to `get_str_Debug()` with the arguments used in the `get_str()` call along with two additional arguments, a char pointer to the source file name where the `get_str()` is being replaced by the `get_str_Debug()` and the source file line number.